# Close process used by a piece of code in c#

Tags: c#, file, process, directory

i have this code

```
path = textBox1.Text;
dir = @"C:\htmlcsseditor\" + path + ".html";
System.IO.File.Create(dir);
```

but when i try to write on the file the debug says me that the file is used by another process; how can i close the process that uses the file?
Thanks

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should dispose your file, because it stays opened.

```
path = textBox1.Text;
dir = @"C:\htmlcsseditor\" + path + ".html";
using (System.IO.File.Create(dir)) {} // or System.IO.File.Create(dir).Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

> The FileStream object created by this method has a default FileShare
>   value of None; no other process or code can access the created file
>   until the original file handle is closed.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
    Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
    // Add some information to the file.
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

Here how you should create file and write some text in the file. You are closing the process when you are leaving the using block. On the end of using is called `Dispose()` method which is freeing the resource.